# jquery load variable won't load contents

Tags: jquery-load

Hi I am using jQuery load to grab a ahref from a link and then I want to load a div from the page im getting into a div so have tried this:

```
// lets load the contents
$('#navigationLinks a:not(:first-child)').click(function(event){

    $('#wrapper').animate({
        'left':'0px'
    });

    var href = $('#navigationLinks a').attr('href');
    $('#content').load(href + ' #resultDiv');

    event.preventDefault();

});
```

This is the HTML:

```
<div id="navigationLinks">
    <a href="index.html" id="dashboardHome">Dashboard Home</a>
    <a href="industry-overview.html" title="Industry Overview" class="first currentLink">Industry Overview</a>
    <a href="regions.html" title="Regions">Regions</a>
    <a href="industries.html" title="Industries">Industries</a>
    <a href="security-pipeline.html" title="Security Pipeline">Security Pipeline</a>
    <a href="audit-events-issues.html" title="Audit Events &amp; Issues">Audit Events &amp; Issues</a>
    <a href="account-filter.html" title="Account Filter">Account Filter</a>
    <a href="contractual-delivered-services.html" title="Contractual vs. Delivered Services" class="last">Contractual vs. Delivered Services</a>
</div>
```

I tried removing the space in ' #resultDiv' before the # but that didn't help, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Sorry I don't know the answer, but can you console.log() and confirm all the pieces are working: 1. event is firing 2. href is valid 3. that query for #content is returning something?
Note you can use `var href = jQuery(this).attr('href');`. More efficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try this

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$('#navigationLinks a:not(:first-child)').click(function(e){
   var href = e.target;
   $('#content').load(href + ' #resultDiv');
   e.preventDefault();

});
});
```

The problem was that `var href = $('#navigationLinks a').attr('href');`  will always get the first link in the block and not the actually link that was clicked.

Comment: var href = e.target; - this didn't work by loading the url in the div with id of resultDiv